# CodeIgniter and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

I want to create an app using CI and angularjs. When I launch the app for the first time it works perfectly, but if I click another link, the page change but not the url. And when I remove the ng-app from the root url the app works perfectly too. Can you help me please?

this is the content of my template:

```
<html class="animations front fluid top-full menuh-top sticky-top" ng-app="myApp">
....
<body ng-controller="DefaultController">
<?= $content ?>
....
```

and in my controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $data['page'] ='index';
    $this->load->view('index',$data);   
}
```

Comment: please provide some codes to know about what you do....

Comment: I use template because I want to change the content dynamically